# Validator.TryValidateObject always returns true

Tags: c#

I am writing a simple model validator to check data read from configuration files, I'm using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`

When I call

```
bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, validationContext, results);
```

It always returns true. I've tried `[StringLength(5)]` and `[MaxLength(5)]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, validationContext, results, true);
```

Note: `validateAllProperties = true`

Documentation says:

> true to validate all properties; if false, only required attributes
>   are validated..

Brilliant design.

Comment: Was this always that way or have they added this parameter recently?

Comment: @MariuszJamro At least as far back as .NET Framework 4.0, ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.tryvalidateobject?view=net-8.0 see Applies to

Comment: Were it me my vote would have been a flag to OnlyValidateRequired or some such by default `false` so it did all - but that is likely more expensive to do MIGHT have been the choice sometime way back when...who knows